# aggregating data from accross multiple google sheets and querying on them

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with several sheets which all have the same structure:

### [image: sheet structure]

I'd like to make statistics across all those sheets, so for instance on the first sheet I'd like to have a sheet where I could query how many Red titan with 11* or more have we killed, what's the damage dealt vs member name for a titan of a certain color across all the titans we have killed, is there a titan color we struggle mostly against (i.e. escaped titan vs titan color), etcetera. So ideally I think I'd need a way to aggregate data from all sheets after that 'main stats' sheet, to the end and use the query function or something like that. But I haven't managed yet to get anything to work. Is it possible to do it?

the sheet can be viewed there: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RJOgX1S4cIqjakYqtyR5jpsJkkbeZoeUlgVDgOOex0s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Where is the data coming from and what shape does it have? What exactly do you want to do with that data? How should the destination table look like, what fields should it have?

Comment: Data is entered manually. First sheet contains named ranges, the second sheet will be the stats sheet where I want to perform some querie that'll need to aggregate data across the other sheets, the other sheets are the actual data. Example1: display a chart of the average damage of all members for all dark 11* titans. i.e. need to scan all the sheets where B3 is Dark and B4 is 11, collect {A8:A37;B8:B37} and average the damage per member and display it in a chart. Example2: how many 11* Dark Titan have escaped ? here, check all sheets where B3 is Dark, B4 is 11 and where F2 is TITAN ESCAPED